# Why doesn't my state change in my stateful widget even when I pass data through constructors flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello guys i have two stateful widget `InactiveCustomersListView` and `MessageCustomerHeader`

`InactiveCustomersListView` has a List of tiles, and these tiles have checkboxes

```
class InactiveCustomersListView extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool checkAll;
  const InactiveCustomersListView({
    Key key,
    this.checkAll,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InactiveCustomersListView> createState() =>
      _InactiveCustomersListViewState();
}

class _InactiveCustomersListViewState extends State<InactiveCustomersListView> {
  bool checkAll;
  List<CheckBoxModel> listOfCustomers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    listOfCustomers.addAll({
      CheckBoxModel(selected: false),
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = Get.put(CustomersController());
    return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: listOfCustomers.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Obx(() {
            return Container(
              color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
              child: ListTile(
                contentPadding: controller.isCheboxVisible.isTrue
                    ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 22, top: 10, bottom: 10)
                    : EdgeInsets.only(left: 22, right: 22, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                horizontalTitleGap: 5,
                leading: controller.isCheboxVisible.isTrue
                    ? Visibility(
                        visible: controller.isCheboxVisible.value,
                        child: Transform.scale(
                          scale: 1.3,
                          child: Checkbox(
                            side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                                if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                                  return const BorderSide(
                                      width: 2, color: Color(0xff34495E));
                                }
                                return const BorderSide(
                                    width: 1, color: Color(0xffB0BEC1));
                              },
                            ),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                            activeColor: Color(0xff34495E),
                            //materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                            //visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                            value: listOfCustomers[index].selected,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                listOfCustomers[index].selected = value;

                                final check = listOfCustomers
                                    .every((element) => element.selected);
                                checkAll = check;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : null,
                title: Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80)),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          height: 100,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          imageUrl:
                              Get.find<AuthService>().user.value.avatar.thumb,
                          placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                            'assets/img/loading.gif',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 80,
                          ),
                          errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                              Icon(Icons.error_outline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'John Cletus',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    color: Color(0xff151515)),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color(0xffECF0F1),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 10.0,
                                      right: 10.0,
                                      top: 5.0,
                                      bottom: 5.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Inactive',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        fontSize: 10,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        color: Color(0xff7F8D90)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    '2',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        color: Color(0xff151515)),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'jobs',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        fontSize: 12,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        color: Color(0xff151515)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Last job 5 days ago',
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 9,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Color(0xff151515)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
        });
  }
}

class CheckBoxModel {
  bool selected;

  CheckBoxModel({this.selected});
}
```

`MessageCustomerHeader` widget class has a checkbox that controls the Check boxes in the `InactiveCustomersListView` widget class:

```
class MessageCustomerHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CheckBoxModel> listOfCustomers;
  const MessageCustomerHeader({
    Key key,
    this.listOfCustomers,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MessageCustomerHeader> createState() => _MessageCustomerHeaderState();
}

class _MessageCustomerHeaderState extends State<MessageCustomerHeader> {
  bool checkAll = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Select customers you woult like to message',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: Color(0xff596780).withOpacity(0.8),
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Transform.scale(
                  scale: 1.3,
                  child: Checkbox(
                    side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                          return const BorderSide(
                              width: 2, color: Color(0xff34495E));
                        }
                        return const BorderSide(
                            width: 1, color: Color(0xffB0BEC1));
                      },
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    activeColor: Color(0xff34495E),
                    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                    visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: -4, vertical: -4),
                    value: checkAll,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        checkAll = value;
                        widget.listOfCustomers.forEach((element) {
                          element.selected = value;
                        });
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Select all',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Colors.black87,
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using constructor to pass "listOfCustomers" from `InactiveCustomersListView` widget to `MessageCustomerHeader` widget

And also passing "checkAll" from `MessageCustomerHeader` to `InactiveCustomersListView` widget by also using constructors.

The problem is having is that when i click on the checkbox in `MessageCustomerHeader` widget to check all the check boxes in `InactiveCustomersListView` widget, the state don't seem to change and it doesn't even after setting all the logic. What am i doing wrong guys and how do i resolve this issue :(

This is the error i get when i tap the checkbox on the `MessageCustomerHeader` checkbox.

"The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (CheckBoxModel) => Null)"

[image: Error on tapping checkbox]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the proper lints enabled you would have seen this warning: `DON'T put any logic in createState().`

From the [associated description](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/no_logic_in_create_state.html):

> Implementations of createState() should return a new instance of a State object and do nothing more. Since state access is preferred via the widget field, passing data to State objects using custom constructor parameters should also be avoided and so further, **the State constructor is required to be passed no arguments.**

(emphasis added)

You are passing arguments to your State constructors. Instead, use `widget.checkAll` and `widget.listOfCustomers` to access widget properties from the state objects.

Also:

- It would be better to specify a type for `checkAll`. In your code you just have `final checkAll;`.
- It is difficult to read the screen shot of the error message. It would be better to include the error message as text in the question, along with an indication in your code of the line to which the error message is referring.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your response, though this does nit answer my question in any way

Comment: You have removed the State constructor arguments and are still observing the same behavior?

Comment: YEs sir, i have updated my code....please check and see what i am doing wrong

Comment: I see. The way the code is written suggests that null safety is disabled. What version of Dart are you using? Is null safety disabled in this project? I recommend enabling null safety if you can, it will help prevent this kind of error. If you can't, you will have to check instantiation sites of `MessageCustomerHeader` because somewhere it's being constructed with a null `listOfCustomers`.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting, i don't think it has to do with null safety as i intentionally disabled null safety on project and had no issue so far, it returns null because listOfCustomers from other widget isn't passed correctly to new widget, so it doesn't have a value